# Binding to property of a null object property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing a utility to create and edit custom data fields in our app suite.  Each data field is called an Element in our code, and each Element has 0 or 1 Requirement objects.  A Requirement object consists of a boolean expression and an error message, both held in memory as strings.

Now, I have a view that has separate tabs, one for the general Element data, and one for the Element's Requirement data.  The viewmodel that serves as the context for the view has a public Element property.  My problem is, the bindings on the general tab work fine (ie. `Text="{Binding Element.Description}"`).  However, the bindings on the Requirement (`Text = "{Binding Element.Requirement.Condition}"`) tab do not work if the Element's Requirement property is null when the view loads.  Looking at the Element object when I hit a breakpoint, the Requirement property is still null, even after entering data into the textblocks.

I'm using the following in my Element's setter in the viewmodel.

```
public Element Element { 
    get{return _element;}
    set{
        if (value == _element) return;
        if (_element != null) _element.OnPropertyChanged -= ElementChanged;
        _element = value;
        if (_element != null) _element.OnPropertyChanged += ElementChanged;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void ElementChanged(){
    OnPropertyChanged("Element");
}
```

I'm doing the same thing in the Requirement's setter within the Element class, and all three implement from INotifyPropertyChanged.  At this point I'm at a total loss as to what I need to do.

One thing to note: I don't want to set `Element.Requirement = new Requirement()` in my viewmodel's constructor, because that will try to save a blank record to the database.

Comment: Look at the last line of your setter, then look at the method signature of the bottom method.

Comment: You can write a value converter.  It receives an instance of Object when change happens, you then parse the properties and set them to the non null values you want, such as string.empty;